# Regex match pattern end with ':' but not include it

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regex and i don't find how to get text before ':' but not include it.

I do a replace in my code so i need to select all the text after ':'

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS2pH9/6):

```
/(?!.*:)./
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See this: https://regex101.com/r/aS2pH9/7

Comment: Please share the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the required output is only character names: Hilary:
Devon
Hilary
Devon
Hilary

Comment: /(?>.*:)/ try this

Comment: So, [`.replace(/:.*/g, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/aS2pH9/8)? Or just split with `:` and grab the first item.

Comment: If matching then use: `/^[^:]*/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution is good but there is some problems: https://regex101.com/r/aS2pH9/9

Comment: Here is my function: `<script>`lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
        line.replace(/:.*/g, '*')
        .split('*')
        .forEach(function (word) {
        if (word.length > 0)
            console.log(word);
            /* console.log(word.replace(':', '')); */
        })
    })`</script>`

Comment: I see you have multiline input, right? Use `s.match(/^[^:\r\n]+(?=:)/gm)`. If the names cannot have a space, you might use `s.match(/^\S+(?=:)/gm)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay but how iter on each after this ?

Comment: What do you mean? See https://jsfiddle.net/0khf1s4w/

Comment: Thank you all for your help. @WiktorStribiżew ty for your solution with JSON it's what i wanted.

Comment: @amerej It seems quite different from what we thought you need. I posted an answer, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need

```js
const rx = /^[^:\r\n]+(?=:)/gm;
const str = `Hilary: YOU KNOW, THIS IS NOT WHY I CAME HERE.
Devon: DOESN'T MATTER.
Hilary: IT DOES. DEVON, WHEN I SAY THAT I'M TIRED OF SNEAKING AROUND, I MEANT IT.
Devon: DON'T GET UPSET, THOUGH.
Hilary: HOW CAN I NOT? I MEAN, LOOK AT WHAT I DID.
Devon: HONEY, HONEY, WE'RE IN LOVE WITH EACH OTHER. OKAY? AND WE KNOW EXACTLY WHAT WE HAVE TO DO. WE'RE GONNA TELL NEIL THE TRUTH.
Hilary: NOW?
Dr. Barrett: I THINK YOU CAN PROVIDE SOME VALUABLE INSIGHT INTO PHYLLIS NEWMAN'S RECENT STATE OF MIND.`;
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(str.match(rx), 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^:\r\n]+` - one or more chars other than `:`, CR and LF
- `(?=:)` -  there must be `:` immediately to the right of the current location